# React Router with Express, subpages are not routing correctly in production

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, react-router

I have a React app built with react router and express hosted on Heroku. I can navigate to the homepage ('/') to other pages ('/about') fine, but if I try to navigate directly to a subpage (e.g. '/about') from the browser, Express returns a 500 error.

I tried to always return the index.html page regardless of the request, and then let React Router handle the routing but something is implemented incorrectly. This is only happening in `production` on Heroku; my local dev environment routing works fine.

Images are also broken on non-root pages.

**File Structure:**

```
build
..static
....css
....js
....media
node_modules
public
server
..server.js
src
..config
....switch.js
..imgs
..pages
..scss
..App.js
..index.js
package.json
Procfile
README.md
static.json
```

**server.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect').default;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(sslRedirect());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile('index.html');
  });
} else {
  const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');app.use(express.static(publicPath));app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}!`);
  });
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'
import Switch from './config/switch'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import './App.scss'

const App = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
`

const AppContent = styled.div`
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-grow: 99;
  @media (max-width: 1200px) {
    width: 96vw;
  }
`

function AppComponent({history}) {
  return (
    <App>
      <AppContent>
        <Header history={history}/>
        <Switch />
      </AppContent>  
      <Footer />
    </App>

  );
}

export default AppComponent
```

**switch.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
// Components
import Home from '../pages/home'
import About from '../pages/about'

  render () {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(SwitchComponent)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `app.get` handler in the production environment to

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build", "index.html"), err => {
           if (err) {
               console.log(err);
           }
       });
   });
```